# why do i get the GS200 error when setting up safe?

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, mocha, gnosis

I'm trying to set up a gnosis safe with two owners and threshold of two but i keep getting this error and i'm not sure why.
I checked my inputs with other scripts the have the same type of inputs which seems really confusing.

```
export async function createSafe() {
  const { daoMember1, daoMember2, daoMember3, daoMember4 } = await getAccounts()
  // Deploy three Gnosis Safe contract

  // Deploy Gnosis Safe master copy contract
  const masterCopyFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafe')
  const masterCopy = await masterCopyFactory.deploy()

  // Deploy Gnosis Safe proxy factory contract
  const proxyFactoryFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafeProxyFactory')
  const proxyFactory = await proxyFactoryFactory.deploy()

  // Create Gnosis Safe contract

  const safeProxy = await proxyFactory.createProxy(masterCopy.address, '0x')
  const safe = await ethers.getContractAt('GnosisSafe', masterCopy.address)

  // Set up Gnosis Safe contract with owners and threshold
  await safe.setup(
    [daoMember1.address, daoMember2.address],
    2,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    '0x',
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    0,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero
  )

  return safe
}
```

this is the error :

```
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'GS200'
    at GnosisSafe.addOwnerWithThreshold (@gnosis.pm/safe-contracts/contracts/base/OwnerManager.sol:53)
    at GnosisSafe.setup (contracts/GnosisSafe.sol:86)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1819:23)
    at async HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:508:16)
    at async EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1522:18)
    at async HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:123:18)
    at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are still using the master copy's `address` as the Gnosis Safe contract `address`, use `safeProxy` instead

replace this part `const safe = await ethers.getContractAt('GnosisSafe', masterCopy.address)`

with

```
const safe = await ethers.getContractAt('GnosisSafe', safeProxy)
```